# Kivy App for Android Unable to Load Image

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer, file-access

My Kivy app deployed to Android via Buildozer no longer launches properly on Android since I have added .jpg and .wav files (used as background images and app sounds). It runs just fine  on my Window machine.

`adb catlog` gives me the following warning: `Unable to load image </data/user/0/org.test.galaxy/files/app/assets/images/bg1.jpg>`. But the kicker is that if I navigate to this filepath within my android emulator, that file indeed exists.

[View all my code in this public repo](https://github.com/Aoshua/kivy-playground/tree/main/galaxy)

This error is thrown when executing line 10 of my `galaxy.kv` which attempts to set the background info of my Rectangle with `source: root.resource_path('assets/images/bg1.jpg')`

Originally, I was just using relative pathing and leaving it all up to Buildozer to handle the OS specific pathing (I've read someplace that this is supposed to work), but since I have this error, I've included the `resource_path()` (credit to someone on stackoverflow) method which is supposed to take the OS specific pathing into account. Here is what that code looks like:

```
def resource_path(self, relative_path):
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    print('base path:', base_path)
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Some relevant lines from my `buildozer.spec` (again, view my whole repo with the link above):

```
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,wav,ttf
...
requirements = python3,kivy
```

I'm new to Kivy and Buildozer and I've obviously missed something about how to access static files. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: For future reference, after @JonathanRoux pointed out the resolution being the issue, I removed all use of `resource_path()` and it still works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may be due to the too high resolution of your bg image.
Try again with a smaller image.

Comment: Many thanks! I swapped it for a lower resolution image and now it works. How would I get this to work with a larger resolution image? I've been following your Kivy tutorial to ultimately build a different Kivy app for a 4K Android smart TV, so large image files will be necessary.